# Get value of parent item using child slug ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm stuck in getting parent ng-repeat value using child ng-repeat slug. It shows nothing just blank td's

What I've done

```
$scope.column = [column_id: "12"slug: "item6"sort: "0"status: "1"title: "Contact no"ts_datetime: "2014-12-12 12:27:50"];

$scope.column.item = [item1: "1"item2: "2"item3: "3"item4: "4"item5: "5"item6: "8"item_id: "1"status: "1"]
```

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in columns" >{{ column.title }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in listings">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-init="val = item.column.slug">{{ val }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want is this. to get the value of item with the slug of column. Like item.column.slug

Comment: What's the contents of `columns` and `listings`?

Comment: the contents are just values

Comment: I mean, add the variables' contents to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{item[column].slug}}</td>
```

Comment: done by this <td ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-init="val = item[column.slug]">{{val}}</td> :)